# Populating Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I am using a Google Custom Search Engine widget in my site. I have a search page, and then an overall site search.

When a User enters a search term in the overall search site, I want to redirect them to the search page and populate their search criteria into the Google Custom Search Engine field.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to set the Google CSE field.

My site:
https://municipalagenda.com/

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchCriteria = '@Model.SearchCriteria';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (searchCriteria != null) {
            setTimeout($("#gsc-i-id1").innerHTML = searchCriteria, 1000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I verified that I am getting the searchCriteria passed into the page correctly.  It's just a matter of taking that value and stuffing it into a TEXT Input.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using setTimeout correctly.  Argument 1 needs to be a function:

```
setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)
```

so

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $("#gsc-i-id1").innerHTML = searchCriteria;
}, 1000);
```